# Rename file from incoming http POST using php

Tags: php

I am trying to rename a file that I am accepting via http POST. Please see the code:

```
<?php
$xmlData = fopen('php://input' , 'rb');
while (!feof($xmlData)) { $xmlString .= fread($xmlData, 4096); }
fclose($xmlData);

file_put_contents('temp/message' . date('m-d-y') . '-' . time() . '.xml', $xmlString, FILE_APPEND);

$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($xmlString);

$id = trim($xml->MSG->ID);
$receiver = trim($xml->MSG->RECEIVER);
$message = trim($xml->MSG->MESSAGE);
$sender = trim($xml->MSG->SENDER);
$binary = trim($xml->MSG->BINARY);
$sent = trim($xml->MSG->SENT);

foreach ($xml->{'line-items'}->{'line-item'} as $lineItem) {
  array_push($messageTitles, trim($lineItem->title));
}

header('HTTP/1.0 200 OK');
exit();
```

Now I am at a slight loss at how to rename this?

Comment: What do you want to rename? The `temp/message...`-file? Use a different path/name in the file_put_contents-statement...

Comment: I need to save the file so I can then process the xml and rename to one of the fields from the xml being passed to me? ie: <RECEIVER>1234</RECEIVER> then 1234 will be in the file name

Comment: Well, I was offline during the last hour, but I'm glad to see @cc took care of the issue. No need to save the file before processing the data...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't even need to save the file in order to process the XML tree. So you can process the file and move the `file_put_contents(...)` at the end.

```
<?php
$xmlData = fopen('php://input' , 'rb');
while (!feof($xmlData)) { $xmlString .= fread($xmlData, 4096); }
fclose($xmlData);

$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($xmlString);

$id = trim($xml->MSG->ID);
$receiver = trim($xml->MSG->RECEIVER);
$message = trim($xml->MSG->MESSAGE);
$sender = trim($xml->MSG->SENDER);
$binary = trim($xml->MSG->BINARY);
$sent = trim($xml->MSG->SENT);

foreach ($xml->{'line-items'}->{'line-item'} as $lineItem) {
  array_push($messageTitles, trim($lineItem->title));
}

file_put_contents("temp/$receiver.xml", $xmlString, FILE_APPEND); // warning: security issue here

header('HTTP/1.0 200 OK');
exit();
```

Please note that you should enforce security restrictions to prevent the user from naming your file with an arbitrary name.